# Slidedown animation hides div during animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

I have the following code: http://jsfiddle.net/4QF4C/7/

When you press `Click Me!`, why does it hide the red square during the animation and then show it after the animation is over?

HTML:

```
<div class="container">  
    <div class="static-box">
        This is a static box that isn't effected by JQuery.
        <div class="dot"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        This is just some text.
        <div class="dot"></div>
    </div>
    <a href="#">Click Me!</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    border-left: 5px solid black;
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 250px;
    width: 550px;
}

.static-box {
    width: 500px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.box {
    width: 500px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: none;
}

.dot {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    background-color: red;
    top: 50%;
    left: -21px;
    margin-top: -7px;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$('a').click(function() {
    $(".box").hide().slideDown();
    $("a").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because when slidedown animates, the parent div (div.box) has overflow set to hidden. This is part of jQuery's internal css while it animates. You need to either position the parent div to encompass the div.dot in it's visible area, or override that to

```
overflow:visible !important
```

Adding this to your CSS will solve your problem:

```
div.box{
 overflow:visible !important;   
}
```

However, this messes with how the slidedown effect works. You're much better off increasing the width of the sliding element, otherwise its content will be visible while it slides, which basically destroys the slidedown effect.

Cheers

Comment: It seems I didn't do the JSFiddle according to how I have it. Here's a new thread for the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20913414/blind-hides-div-during-animation

Comment: You might consider accepting this answer or closing the question, then.