# Blind hides div during animation

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui, jquery

I have the following: http://jsfiddle.net/4QF4C/14/

Why does the red square hide behind the black line during the animation and then show after it's done? How can I fix this?

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">  
        <div class="box-static">
            This is a static box that isn't effected by JQuery.
            <div class="dot"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            This is just some text.
            <div class="dot"></div>
        </div>
        <a href="#">Click Me!</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 900px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.content {
    width: 550px;
    float: right;
    border-left: 5px solid black;
    position: relative;
    height: 250px;
}

.box-static {
    width: 500px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 12px; 
    margin: 10px 0 0 17px;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.dot {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background-color: red;
    top: 50%;
    left: -28px;
    margin-top: -8px;
}

.dot:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    background-color: white;
    top: 4px;
    left: 4px;
}

.box {
    width: 500px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 12px; 
    margin: 10px 0 0 17px;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: none;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$('a').click(function() {
    $(".box").hide().show("blind");
    $("a").hide();
});
```

Please help!

Comment: @ManofSnow Yes, it is - very briefly. During the `.show('blind')` method, the left side is behind the line until animation completed. Even if change animation type to `.show('fade')` the middle of the box is hidden behind the line until completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you're after: http://jsfiddle.net/4QF4C/32/

Basically all I did was change the following:

```
.box {
    left: -11px; // Added
    margin: 10px 0 0 28px; // Changed the margin-left portion to add 11px
    overflow: visible; // Added this; not sure if it's necessary
}
```

This makes the `.box` expand to include the `.dot`, and be over the black line.

Answer (score 0):

The `Blind` effect will give the container an `overflow:hidden`, so height changes affect what's visible.

### Great.  So how do I fix it?

You can easily fix it by choosing another effect, such as **linear** or changing the `direction` parameter to `horizontal` or so (`'Blind', {direction:'bottom'}`)

However, this will change the effect, so you could create your own function because the element's height change will effect **what's visible.**

**[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4QF4C/28/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try using fadeIn instead of show

Comment: That's not the effect I'm going for.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a').click(function() {
    $(".box").slideDown();
    $("a").hide();
});
```

This sounds to me the one you want, or fadeIn() like Justin said.